# Using a subset of a fact table for another fact table?

Tags: sql-server, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I'm pretty new to data warehousing so I'm not sure whether the question makes any sense. 
I have a Sales fact table that shows the purchases by customers. This table is connected to dimension tables like Customers and Product.

I plan to have a PromotionStatus fact table that tracks the response of customers (No response, Further enquiry, etc etc) which is linked to the PromotionInfo and Customers dimension tables. The problem is the promotion is aimed at a group of customers based on their purchasing habits which can be obtained from the Sales fact table.

Is it possible to directly populate the PromotionStatus fact table with customers that qualify using the Sales fact table? Or is this a stupid idea in general and I'm better off manually extracting the customers via a query and pushing them to the PromotionStatus table?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a view for this?  Write the query that connects the necessary tables and encapsulate this in a view.  I'm not sure what other technologies you're working with, but a view can be used just like a table would in many of the other Microsoft tools such as SSRS and SSAS.